# Three.js objloader not rendering

Tags: javascript, three.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1zh5.jpg)

Error : Function expected anonymous function

I used Three.js objloader

```
    const loader = new OBJLoader();
    loader.load("object/teddy.obj", (root) => {
        scene.add(root);
    }, () => { }, (e) => { console.log(e) });
```

This code works fine in chrome

but Doesn't work in Edge browser and throws the above error
edge version 44.18362.449.0

https://github.com/WBCode2/Three.js/blob/master/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Three.JS is intended to work on modern browsers. You are able to see a list of WebGL supported browsers [here](https://caniuse.com/webgl). You will notice that it says WebGL is supported by Edge, however only using `experimental-webgl`. There is a good answer for that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41325390/difference-between-webgl-and-experimental-webgl).

**In short:** Update your Microsoft Edge to latest version (v44.18362.449.0 is no where near latest). See Three.js compatibility list [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/12698).